# ContainerRequestContext.abortWith(Response response) does not work

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I tried RESTEasy's (WildFly 16) abortWith(Response response) but did not work. I have multiple abortWith medhods. Such as,

```
if(fails1){
   System.out.printn("fails 1");
   abortWith(...)
}
if(fails2){
   System.out.printn("fails 2");
   abortWith(...);
}
```

If fails1 and fails2 are true, both abortWith methods are executed. The fails1's abortWith does not return response unless I put "return".

```
if(fails1){
   System.out.printn("fails 1");
   abortWith(...);
   return;
}
```

Do I need to put return after abortWith?
Can I throw WebApplicationException to break filter chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ContainerRequestContext.abortWith()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta/ws/rs/container/containerrequestcontext#abortWith(jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response)) aborts the filter chain, not the current filter being processed. You can either add the return statement like you suggest or throw a `WebApplicationException` to raise and exception.